# Building a Visual Basic script that uses a batch file

Tags: visual-studio, variables, vbscript, batch-file

I've written a batch file script that takes an image sequence from a certain folder, converts it to quicktime using ffmpeg and then it moves the file to a certain folder.

I used variables at the beginning of the batch script for user input on which folder to take the files from.

And now for my question: The batch I've written works just fine but I want to make it into a simple visual basic script so it looks nice and clean instead of a command prompt interface.

Can anyone provide me with tips for the VB code?
How do I pass variables from VB to the batch file?

Any help on this would be much appriciated.

Comment: To clarify, you want a Visual Basic GUI program to take the users input and then feed that input into your batch script. correct?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [HTML Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to program the GUI to gather the info needed from the user. Use WScript.Shell's .Run or .Exec method to start an external process (either the .bat or ffmpeg directly) and pass those info via the command line.